# jhipster:upgrade never completes

Tags: jhipster

**UPDATE:
I performed my upgrade using the manual steps and it worked fine.
Afterwards, I noticed that version 4.3.0 has a new --verbose flag, so I ran it again with the --force flag.  It still hangs with no error at `yarn run webpack:build`.**

**I then ran `yarn webpack:build` by itself.  It looked like it completed everything, but did not return control to the console.  I noticed a yellow message box in my taskbar notification area, that says 'JHipster' [Notification Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX9ki.png).  When I click on that notification, the job completes and control returns to the console.  (I have noticed this notification looks different on Win10 and I don't think it requires a click to dismiss.)**

**This notification does not appear when running jhipster:upgrade, so I am guessing that is what is hanging up the process.**

(original post)

I have generated a jhipster project (4.1.1) and have been working with it.  I tried to run jhipster:upgrade to 4.2.0 but the process never completes. (I left it overnight.)

I set up and repeated this process on another computer, and it runs fine.

I have tried to identify why/where the process is hanging on my main computer but have been unsuccessful.

Anyone have some steps, tips to identify what is going wrong?

My environment:

```
Win7 Enterprise
java version "1.8.0_74"
git version 2.12.0.windows.1
node v6.10.2
yarn 0.21.3
```

Command output:

```
C:\applications\jhipster\formsLib>yo jhipster:upgrade
Welcome to the JHipster Upgrade Sub-Generator
This will upgrade your current application codebase to the latest JHipster version
Looking for latest generator-jhipster version...
New generator-jhipster version found: 4.2.0
Git repository detected
Updating generator-jhipster to 4.2.0 . This might take some time...
```

Several node processes kick off and run for a while, but then they go idle.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling node and yarn.

I enabled `NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,fs,tls,module,timers node` and reran it.  The last few lines before it stalls are:

```
NET 15272: _read
NET 15272: onread 21
NET 15272: got data
NET 15272: _read
NET 15272: onread 33
NET 15272: got data
NET 15272: _read
NET 15272: onread 73
NET 15272: got data
NET 15272: _read
```

process 15272 is `node "C:\Users\mbaxley\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\.bin\\..\yo\lib\cli.js" jhipster:upgrade`

[View Remaining Node Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SckWh.png)

The only file updated during the process is the package.json file.  Here is the diff of the modified file:

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 7a2a6b8..eb7de34 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -16,11 +16,11 @@
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
     "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
     "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.21",
+    "angular2-cookie": "1.2.6",
     "angular2-infinite-scroll": "0.3.4",
     "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
-    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
-    "angular2-cookie": "1.2.6",
     "core-js": "2.4.1",
+    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
     "jquery": "3.1.1",
     "ng-jhipster": "0.1.9",
     "ng2-webstorage": "1.5.1",
@@ -47,7 +47,7 @@
     "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
     "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
     "file-loader": "0.10.1",
-    "generator-jhipster": "4.1.1",
+    "generator-jhipster": "4.2.0",
     "html-loader": "0.4.5",
     "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
     "image-webpack-loader": "3.2.0",
@@ -65,9 +65,12 @@
     "lazypipe": "1.0.1",
     "lodash": "4.17.4",
     "map-stream": "0.0.6",
+    "node-sass": "4.5.0",
     "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.14",
+    "postcss-loader": "1.3.0",
     "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
     "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
+    "sass-loader": "5.0.1",
     "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
     "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.3",
     "style-loader": "0.14.0",
@@ -81,9 +84,6 @@
     "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
     "write-file-webpack-plugin": "3.4.2",
     "xml2js": "0.4.17",
-    "sass-loader": "5.0.1",
-    "node-sass": "4.5.0",
-    "postcss-loader": "1.3.0",
     "yargs": "6.6.0"
   },
   "engines": {
```

Comment: This has been reported by few other users who all seem to run on Windows https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5485 Only suggestion is to run manually all the instructions as found in the sub generator code to determine the root cause. Console output should also be more verbose.